# Excel pivot table - combining data from three columns. Power query?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table, power-query

My income is divided into three portions - cash, bank transaction, and USD. Let's say they are in columns A to C respectively. The total income is:

total income = column A + column B + column C * exchange rate

I could create a help column to do the total income calculation and use it in a pivot table. However, I wonder if there is a way to avoid doing so. Could power query help in this case?

Comment: Better add some sample data & expected output,,, help us to fix the issue,, also be specific that what you are suppose to do with Help Col ,,, this all can be done without PT & PQ too!

Comment: You might even do it with pivot table calculation : https://www.contextures.com/excel-pivot-table-calculated-field.html

Comment: @Máté Juhász I had the wrong impression that one couldn't use calculated field in pivot tables. Apparently, I was wrong. Thanks.